# Conditional chaining operator for type doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to extract a type from within an object where every field can be undefined. However, when I attempt to use the conditional chaining operator, it throws an error
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
type a = { one?: { two?: { three: string } } };
type threeType = a['one']?.['two']?.['three'];
```

It gives error even in ts playgound with last version of typescript

I tried to use the conditional chaining operator, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: "it throws an error" — Is the error message a secret?

Comment: You can try something like:

`type threeType = a extends { one?: { two?: { three: infer T } } } ? T : never;`

but I'm looking for something shorter

Comment: Where did you get the idea you _could_ do that?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina thanks, i think its the only solution

Comment: @jonrsharpe we can do it in JavaScript; I thought we could do it in TypeScript too.

Comment: "@ChristianVincenzoTraina, I found a flaw in this code snippet: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code=C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeB7AdhA-ALmVYA7ijlAK5oAmEAZgJYYUC+jAUKJFBgQCrjSJwIAD2ARKAZzzosuJPiIk5wABYAnCBFz1qEVVG5RGh45n1RcGAG66A3EA. It returns an 'unknown' type if one of the nested fields is undefined.

Comment: @kiborgKiller You playground link is broken.

Comment: There is no optional chaining *type operator* (which is why you get an error); but `NonNullable<T>` has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictnullchecks) disabled this works without compiler error.

```
type A = {one?: {two?: {three: string}}};
type ThreeType = A["one"]["two"]["three"];
// type ThreeType = string;
```

With strictNullChecks enabled, you can do that with the [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type.

```
type A = {one?: {two?: {three: string}}};
type ThreeType = NonNullable<NonNullable<NonNullable<A['one']>>['two']>['three'];
// type ThreeType = string;
```

Comment: i thought so too but it doest work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeB7AdhA-ALmcA7ijngBYBOEEuAzsGQJZoDmAvmwNwBQokUAKuUp9w0RDADaAInQRJAXSkEU8xYNlz2QA

Comment: @kiborgKiller Thanks for pointing out. I was experimenting on `strict: false`.